# C# Winform search value on datagrid error

Tags: c#, mysql, search, datagridview

I have a "Search" button to search data/cell in datagrid which is source mysql db. The code block below is success to search for only a column but when i add for other columns than searching functioning doesn't work well and mostly not bring results. As well given error for case-sensitive which is not a problem for only one column.

How can i arrange the code to be able to search all rows and columns?

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            dgvEkip.DataSource = DV;

            // I added those columns below for search function as well but did not work well
            /*
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Telephone LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Email LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Surname LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("City LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Adress LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            */
        }
```

Thanks a lot, Nuri.

Comment: did you try to use OR? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put more conditions in a logic OR: for example

```
 DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%' OR Telephone LIKE '%{0}%' OR Email LIKE '%{0}%' ", txtSearch.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AND to join conditions like this:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Telephone LIKE '%{0}%' AND Email LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text, txtSearch2.Text);
```

Comment: both OR and AND worked very well. Thanks for help @McNets